# XMLHttpRequest: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)
>   [XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://… Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479694/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr)

I am trying to open my JSON file such as:

```
jQuery.getJSON('../data/json/en/nodesData.json',
      function(data){
           jQuery.each(data, function(){
                  //do something...
           })
     })
```

this yields the following error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/URL/data/json/en/nodesData.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

what's problem? How can I retrieve my json?

Comment: Is this script on a page on your local machine or on the web?

Comment: I am working on my local machine. my application is based on Jquery

Comment: Can you install a webserver on your local machine?  That would make this work, and make your life easier.  http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: No I cant, it is not goal of project what I am developping

Comment: What *is* your goal?  Because if it involves AJAX calls, you're gonna want a web server.  Without it you're gonna have a hard time, like you are seeing now.

Comment: My goal is to import data from JSON file within utilization a variable.
I founded a way by AJAX calls to make import, but there is probleme for Chrome

Comment: @RocketHazmat I want to underline that loading a local JSON file is a reasonable goal. I want to do this too because I want to create a locally working webapp, that preloads data from a JSON file. I now ran into the very same problem than the OP.

Comment: @Marcel: That's what localStorage and/or IndexedDB is for.  It'd be a **MAJOR** security hazard if a web browser could load arbitrary files from your hard drive without your knowledge.

Comment: @RocketHazmat not "arbitrary", but a local file in the same directory, loaded from an html file, I just double-clicked on. But, talking about localStorage and IndexedDB, is there any way to prepare these. BEFORE my html page gets double-clicked?

Comment: @Marcel: You prepare them in your page, before your code. (Oh, and there's the File System API too)

Comment: @Marcel: For security purposes, browsers restrict `file:///` urls from doing things.

Answer (score 4):

You really should be running a local server like Apache or IIS to run HTML/JavaScript code so you do not run into these restrictions.

You can start the browser up with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files` which removes the restriction.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you cannot make AJAX calls to your local file system.  Some browsers allow this, but others don't.  Chrome has a flag that enables this, but it's off by default.

Comment: Is it possible configure Chrome to accept this request?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You cannot load the file because technically it is located in another domain. You need to call it like `localhost/<Path>/nodesData.json`.

Comment: how I can call via localhost? I have not server, my application is based on Jquery

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy) to make it work in chrome...

Comment: @Valeriane did you look into the link i provided in my last comment and tried to make it owrk?